# How to preview file name like this logo.png?

Tags: javascript

Hi I am trying to preview any filename when I upload to any file from local but the filename is looking like this 
blob:http://localhost/cf1d307b-83ef-452b-ba7b-53af653378ce
but I want to preview file name like this logo.png or logo.jepg or logo.zip
please help me thanks.

**script**

```
function preview_images() 
{
    var total_file=document.getElementById("images").files.length;
    for(var i=0;i<total_file;i++)
    {
          $('#file_preview').append("<div>"+URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i])+" 
                </div>");
    }
}
```

**HTML view**

```
<div class="form-group mb-4">
<label >Upload ArtWork :</label>
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="images" name="images[]" 
                 onchange="preview_images();" multiple/>
                 div class="row" id="file_preview"></div>
```

Comment: [`createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) returns blob URL. Use [`File.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/name) property for that

Comment: can you please edit my code?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```js
function preview_images() 
{
    const files =  document.getElementById("images").files

    const total_files =files.length;
  
    const $preview = $('#file_preview')
    
    $preview.html('')
    
    for(var i=0; i< total_files ;i++)
    {
       const file = files[i]
       const name = file.name
    
       $preview.append(`<p>${name}</p>`);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group mb-4">

<label >Upload ArtWork :</label>

<input type="file" class="form-control" id="images" name="images[]"  onchange="preview_images();" multiple />

<div class="row" id="file_preview"></div>
```